# Python Regex for a specific date format

Tags: python, regex, date

I'm working on a regex expression for a python program where it should find all the dates appear in a text.

According to the assignment's description, the only valid date formats are as the following:

﻿﻿"3/30/18", "3/30/2018", "3-30-2018", "03-30-2018", "30.3.2018", 
"30. 3. 2018", "2018-03-30"

I created a string variable containing the valid formats and added a few to check if my code would work.

```
text_string = 'Examples for valid dates include "3/30/18", "3/30/2018", 
"3-30-2018", "03-30-2018", "30.3.2018", "30. 3. 2018", "2018-03-30", 
"3/30/1", "3/30/201", "/30/18", "3//18", "3/ /18", "3/30/", "3/301/18"'
```

and the following is the regex I came up with:

```
match_string = re.findall('(?:\d{1,2}/\s*\d{1,2}/\s*\d{2,4})| 
(?:\d{1,2}-\s*\d{1,2}-\s*\d{2,4})|(?:\d{4}-\s*\d{1,2}-\s*\d{1,2})| 
(?:\d{1,2}.\s*\d{1,2}.\s*\d{4})', text_string)
```

apparently, my code would capture all 7 valid date formats stated above, but it also returned "3/30/201", which should not be a valid date.

I've tried to add '$' into my code, but it only messed things up more, so I'm wondering how to correct my code to fix this problem.

p.s. This is a Regex assignment, I'm not allowed to use 'datetime' T_T

Comment: First, you need to reformat your code so that it is readable, using the [`re.X`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X) flag.

Comment: If `3/30/201` is not a valid date, why is it included in a string that begins `Examples for valid dates include`?

Comment: @ScottHunter - to quote the OP, _I created a string variable containing the valid formats **and added a few** to check if my code would work._

Comment: @zwer: OK, but the string still is misleading about its content.

Comment: The distinction between `3-30-2018` and `03-30-2018` is ambiguous - the first pattern has to include two digits in the beginning to cover October, November and December, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic part of your regex is this:

```
\d{2,4}
```

This matches 2 to 4 digits - which means 3 digits are also considered a valid year. If you replace the two occurences of `\d{2,4}` with `\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)\b`, the regex works correctly:

```
(?:\d{1,2}/\s*\d{1,2}/\s*\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)\b|(?:\d{1,2}-\s*\d{1,2}-\s*\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)\b|(?:\d{4}-\s*\d{1,2}-\s*\d{1,2})|(?:\d{1,2}.\s*\d{1,2}.\s*\d{4})
```

(Don't forget to use a raw string literal to define the regex: `r'(?:\d{1,2}/\s*\d{1,2}/\s*\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)\b|(?:\d{1,2}-\s*\d{1,2}-\s*\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)\b|(?:\d{4}-\s*\d{1,2}-\s*\d{1,2})|(?:\d{1,2}.\s*\d{1,2}.\s*\d{4})'`)

Output:

```
['3/30/18', '3/30/2018', '3-30-2018', '03-30-2018', '30.3.2018', '30. 3. 2018', '2018-03-30']
```

---

`\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)\b` matches exactly 2 or 4 digits - the `\b` boundary is there to assert that there aren't any more digits, otherwise it would still consider "3/30/201" to be a valid date.

---

Lastly, the regex could be written more concisely as

```
\b\d{1,2}([-/]|\. ?)\d{1,2}\1\d{2}(?:\d{2})?\b|\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b
```

This uses capture groups to assert that no separators are mixed (like `3-2.2018`) and that whitespace is consistent (so things like `1. 2.2018` don't match).

Comment: Be careful with the simplification, while keeping it consistent it will allow for `3- 30- 2018`, I'd rewrite the separator as `([-/]|\. ?)` and skip the second backreference.

Comment: @zwer Good point, thanks. I updated it according to your suggestion.

Comment: thank you guys so much for the response, it's really helpful !!